# Why do Carmelite nuns change headwear?

Tags: catholicism, symbolism, monasticism

In [this movie](https://www.google.com/#q=St+Therese+of+Lisieux+movie) regarding the life of St. Therese of Lisieux, the girl who wants to become a saint, there is a scene wherein she changes the color of her clothing and headdress after participating some time at the monastery. What is the meaning of this color change that marks her becoming a nun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first official stage of the religious life is the noviciate.
Novices are not admitted to vows until they have successfully completed the prescribed period of training and proving, called the novitiate. This usually lasts one year.

This is the period that the member of a religious community undergoes prior to taking vows (poverty, chastity and obedience) in order to discern whether she or he is called to vowed religious life.

The novice's [habit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_habit) is often slightly different from those of professed members of the order. For instance, in communities of women that wear a dark veil over the head, novices often wear a white one (like the case of the [Carmelite Order](http://www.carmelitedcjnorth.org/pages_ministries/motherhouse.html)).

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are happy that you decided to participate. This is a good answer, Carlos, but it really requires a source. As it sits, we just have to take your word for it that you are representing this accurately.

Comment: @fredsbend even if it's common knowledge in a particular group?

Comment: @Anonymous "Common knowledge" within a particular group is an oxymoron.